# Javascript Help - selfDividingNumbers Algorithm producing all 0's

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Greetings Stack Overflow!

First off, this is my first question!

I am trying to solve the selfDividingNumbers algorithm and I ran into this interesting problem. This function is supposed to take a range of numbers to check if they are self dividing.

Self Dividing example:

> ```
> 128 is a self-dividing number because 
>
> 128 % 1 == 0, 128 % 2 == 0, and 128 % 8 == 0.
> ```

My attempt with Javascript.

```
/*      
   selfDividingNumbers( 1, 22 );
*/

var selfDividingNumbers = function(left, right) {
    var output = [];
    while(left <= right){
        // convert number into an array of strings, size 1
        var leftString = left.toString().split();

        // initialize digit iterator
        var currentDigit = leftString[0]; 
        
        for(var i = 0; i < leftString.length; i++){
            currentDigit = parseInt(leftString[i])
            console.log( left % currentDigit );
        }
    
        // increment lower bound
        left++;
    }

    return output
};
```

When comparing the current lower bound to the current digit of the lower bound, **left % currentDigit** it always produces zero! I figure this is probably a type error but I am unsure of why and would love for someone to point out why!

Would also like to see any other ideas to avoid this problem!

I figured this was a good chance to get a better handle on Javascript considering I am clueless as to why my program is producing this output. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Thanks Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `split()` isn't buying you anything. Remove it and you'll get the results you expect. You still have to write the code to populate `output` though.

Comment: Noted your advice on the use of split(). I now see that it was not useful at all to add that in. That seems to be the solution to the bug I was receiving. A misuse of the split() function! 

Thank you so much for your speedy reply! I am now going to try and finish solving this!

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Joseph may fix your current code, but I think there is a potentially easier way to go about doing this.  Consider the following script:

```
var start = 128;
var num = start;
var sd = true;

while (num > 0) {
    var last = num % 10;
    if (start % last != 0) {
        sd = false;
        break;
    }
    num = Math.floor(num / 10);
}

if (sd) {
    print("Is self dividing");
}
else {
    print("Is NOT self dividing");
}
```

### Demo

To test each digit in the number for its ability to cleanly divide the original number, you can simply use a loop.  In each iteration, check `num % 10` to get the current digit, and then divide the number by ten.  If we never see a digit which can not divide evenly, then the number is not self dividing, otherwise it is.

Answer (score 1):

So the string `split` method takes the string and returns an array of string parts. The method expects a parameter, however, the dividing element. If no dividing element is provided, the method will return only one part, the string itself. In your case, what you probably intended was to split the string into individual characters, which would mean the divider would be the empty string:

```
var leftString = left.toString().split('');
```

Since you are already familiar with `console.log`, note that you could also use it to debug your program. If you are confused about the output of `left % currentDigit`, one thing you could try is logging the variables just before the call,

```
console.log(typeof left, left, typeof currentDigit, currentDigit)
```

which might give you ideas about where to look next.